# Bokeh components api fails with error for Bokeh 10.0 with Anaconda (python 2.7) distribution

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, bokeh

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [6, 7, 2, 4, 5]

# output to static HTML file
#output_file("lines.html", title="line plot example")

# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p = figure(title="simple line example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')

# add a line renderer with legend and line thickness
p.line(x, y, legend="Temp.", line_width=2)

p1 = figure(title="simple line example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')

# add a line renderer with legend and line thickness
p1.line(x, y, legend="Temp.", line_width=2)

return components((p, p1))
```

When i run this test program, i get the error as,

```
return components((p, p1))
File "C:\Working\anaconda_python_27\lib\site-packages\bokeh\embed.py" in components
ref = plot_object.ref

Exception Type: AttributeError at /backtest/mavg/
Exception Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ref'
```

Similar error when i pass dictionary to components as `return components({"p":p, "p1": p1})`

Bokeh version 10.0 through anaconda install on windows 64.

Comment: What's the return for?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this with Bokeh 0.10. I notice that your code snippet above does not define `p2` is it possible your `p2` is accidentally something other that a Bokeh plot object? If I make a `p2` that is a figure explicitly:

```
from bokeh.plotting import *
from bokeh.embed import components 
p1 = figure(title="simple line example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')
p1.line(x, y, legend="Temp.", line_width=2)
p2 = figure(title="simple line example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')    
p2.line(x, y, legend="Temp.", line_width=2)
components((p1, p2))
```

Then `components` works as expected. If you still experience a problem I suggest making an issue on the GH issue tracker.

Answer (score -1):

You're executing it improperly, your code works for me. I think the issue is with your misunderstanding of `return components((p, p1))`

A quick test using your code, and having `from bokeh.plotting import show` I got the following:

[image]

Instead of the `return` do `show(p1)`

Comment: `components` is used to embed bokeh plots in in custom templates, which is a common thing to want to do.

Comment: @bigreddot I wasn't sure about `components` but I took it from a python point of view. That's why I said `return components((p, p1))` is confusing, and focused on `return` at the end.